# Require a file once and use it everywhere

Tags: node.js

I've read up on `module.exports` and how it works but I'm not sure if I can accomplish what I want with it - or at least I'm not sure how to. I have some helper functions in a file, one of which is used in a majority of files in my project. I'm wondering if it is possible to just "require" the file one time and then just use it across the entirety of the project when needed.

My file looks something like this:

discord-utils.js

```
const { MessageEmbed, Permissions } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  embedResponse (message, embedOptions, textChannel = null) {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    if (embedOptions.color) embed.setColor(embedOptions.color)
    if (embedOptions.title) embed.setTitle(embedOptions.title)
    if (embedOptions.description) embed.setDescription(embedOptions.description)
    if (embedOptions.url) embed.setURL(embedOptions.url)
    if (embedOptions.author) embed.setAuthor(embedOptions.author)
    if (embedOptions.footer) embed.setFooter(embedOptions.footer)
    if (embedOptions.fields) {
      for (const field of embedOptions.fields) {
        embed.addFields({
          name: field.name,
          value: field.value,
          inline: field.inline ? field.inline : false
        })
      }
    }
    if (textChannel) {
      textChannel.send(embed)
      return
    }
    message.embed(embed)
  },

  inVoiceChannel (voiceState, message, response = null) {
    if (!voiceState.channel) {
      this.embedResponse(message, {
        color: 'RED',
        description: response === null ? 'You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.' : response
      })
      console.warn(`${message.author.tag} attempted to run a music command without being in a voice channel.`)
      return false
    }
    return true
  },

  isAdminOrHasPerms (user, permissionRole) {
    return user.hasPermisssion(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR) || user.hasPermission(permissionRole)
  }
}
```

In pretty much every other file, I use the `embedResponse` function. So in the project I have to do `require('discord-utils)` and then do things like: `discordUtils.embedResponse(blahblah...)` and while that's fine, it seems really redundant since I know I'm going to be using it just about everywhere. I'm wondering if there's a way I can just use one require statement and pull the functions I need at any time?

Comment: Unless there is a way that I am not aware of (I'm not sure if you could do something like this using a transpiler), no this is not possible. In every language I've worked with, if you want to use it, you have to import it.

Answer (score 0):

You may define a globally accessible variable using the `global` object in NodeJS. However, this neither a common nor a recommended pattern in NodeJS.

```js
global.foo = 1 // make the foo variable globally accessible
```

https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Answer (score 0):

Node.js actually has a neat little caching system that can be taken advantage of to achieve a singleton effect. The first time you `require` a file, it runs and sets `module.exports`. Every time you require that same file afterwards, it will return a reference to the same object that was returned the fist time, instead of actually re-executing.

There are some caveats though. It's not always a guarantee that the file won't execute a second time. For example sometimes if you require the file from a very different location far from the first one, it might re-execute the file. Like if you first required the file as `require('./my-file')` and later require it with `require('../../../../my-file')`, it could sometimes re-execute it and clear the cached reference.